# Check winner from arraylist of players in card game

Tags: java, conditional-statements

My card game needs a method to check the winner. Without the draw `if` statement, it works to check that a winning value. However I feel that without a draw check the rest of the project is redundant. How can I do this properly?

```
public String winChecker(){
    Player winningPlayer = players.get(0); 
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (player.getOverallHandValue() > winningPlayer.getOverallHandValue()){
            winningPlayer = player;
        }
        if (player.getOverallHandValue() == winningPlayer.getOverallHandValue()){
            return "draw!";
        }
        return winningPlayer.getName();
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: For one, you only want to declare a draw once you have traversed all players and have determined no one player has a superior hand. Your method as it stands is not guaranteed to check all of them.

Comment: @godhar It's unclear what you are asking for, describe the problem in more detail. This method is flawed,  before anything Java specific you logic is flawed. Consider using pseudocode to describe what should be happening.

Comment: @godhar, did my answer help you? If you need any clarification, please ask in a comment. If my answer has solved your problem, just mark it as solution.

Comment: I think you merely misplaced the `return winningPlayer.getName();`; it should go _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String winChecker(){
    boolean many = false;
    boolean initial = true;
    Player winningPlayer = players.get(0); 
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (player.getOverallHandValue() > winningPlayer.getOverallHandValue()){
            winningPlayer = player;
            many = false;
        }
        if (player.getOverallHandValue() == winningPlayer.getOverallHandValue()){
            if (initial){
                initial = false;
            } else {
                many = true;
            }
        }

    }
    if (many) {
        return "draw";
    }
    return winningPlayer.getName();
}
```

is what you're looking for. In the current code there was a bug which was that in case the results were:

```
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

current code returned "draw" which is obviously wrong. Look, when you're trying to decide which of the players won, you can't decide who is the winner **before reading scores of all players**.

Let's describe both algorithms in English.

1. Set 0th element of players list as current winner.
2. loop through all players
3. if current player has a better score then currently winning, set the current player to currently winning.
4. if they have the same score, decide that the game is drawn. **Look, that on the first iteration it's always true**!

and the second algorithm

1. Set 0th element of players list as current winner.
2. loop through all players
3. if current player has a better score then currently winning, set the current player to currently winning and mark that there is a single leader at the moment.
4. if they have the same score, mark that there are at least two players on lead so there is possibility of a draw.

Comment: Thanks @xenteros, your absolutely right about doing all the checks before declaring things. Thanks again for all the input.

Comment: @godhar if i solved your problem, please mark it as solution

Answer (score -1):

As this code stands you will always get `"draw"` returned.

If the players collection is like this
`["Player A", "Player B", "Player C"]`
Then this line of code
`Player winningPlayer = players.get(0);`
will get you `Player A`.
The problem is, when you iterate over players, the first iteration will get you `Player A` as well.
Therefore
`if (player.getOverallHandValue() == winningPlayer.getOverallHandValue())`
condition will always be true in the first iteration itself.
I think figuring out a way to fix this is best left to your own devices.

Comment: I thought about it. Seems the way to go is nested for loop, checking each element with each element and adding the duplicates to another 'drawers array'. Cannot get it working though!